# Font size in Apple Numbers, Excel and LibreOffice Calc

Tags: ms-office, numbers, font, libreoffice

See the screenshot below. The same font & size with zoom level 100% has different visual sizes in these three macOS spreadsheet apps:

1. Apple Numbers v12.2 (left)
2. Microsoft Excel for Mac v16.69.1 (top right)
3. LibreOffice Calc v7.5 (bottom right)

Has anyone had them look the same using some application settings, GTK settings or so? If you have, please advice us.

Adjusting the spreadsheet zoom level is not an option as it is saved with the file and affects what others see.

[image]
(Click the image to see it in full size.)

The topic has been discussed [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/display-fonts-too-big-on-calc-under-macos/31312) as well.

Comment: Looks like all three applications use a different size. Which one would you consider the master?

Comment: @nohillside, I think Apple Numbers displays the text size correctly.

Comment: I think the question is, what format are you saving the file in?

Comment: @Allan, thank you for the comment. However, if I save an .xlsx file in Excel and open the same file in LibreOffice, the font size in LibreOffice is visually larger.

Comment: That’s unfortunately how LibreOffice translates a native Excel file.  Try saving in the (ODF) format.  We tried to use OpenOffice\LibreOffice to save money (school) and it was a fruitless endeavor because parents who had Excel on their work provided laptops couldn’t reliably open files created in OO/LO for the same reasons you’re experiencing.  The open format solved a lot, but try getting people not under your “control”  to change an application’s default save format.

Comment: I don’t have an answer cause im no expert but I gave up on libre because everything I sent to people who used excel kept having problems

Comment: Yes, LO and Excel aren't fully compatible but I think this problem is not related with the format itself. In the screenshot the files aren't saved at all. I've just started the applications and entered some text in the cells. I can use both Excel and LO to open xlsx and ods and LO always shows fonts larger than Excel does.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't stop using Excel or LibreOffice because I receive different types of files from different people / organizations.

Comment: For what it's worth, Numbers and Excel look the same on my M1 Max MBP.  Libre Office comes close (to half a point) with "View > Page Break" enabled.